# MergExt mergDataGridScroller how to temporary disable scrolling

Tags: scroll, livecode

I am using the mergDataGridScroller in a LiveCode desktop and mobile app and it works fine.
But on mobile, when I show a group on top of the card (on top of the mergDataGridScroller and not related to it) to present a choice to the user for something else, the mergDataGridScroller still react to the mouse/touch moving.
Is there a way to temporary disable the mergDataGridScroller ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Hide the mergDataGridScroller wrapper group which will also hide your data grid and then `dispatch "updateVisible" to group <your mergDataGridScroller group name>`
- Edit the behavior script to add a command something like:

  ```
  command toggleScroller pVisible
    if the environment is "mobile" then
      mobileControlSet sScrollerId, "visible", pVisible
    end if
  end toggleScroller
  ```

Comment: The second option works fine, since it does not hide the scroller behind.